# Is this a valid reformulation of QM?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, schroedinger-equation

So let us consider the Schrodinger equation but written differently:

$$ - i \hbar \lim_{b \to 0}(\frac{\hat U(b t) - I}{b}) \psi = - \hbar^2\lim_{a \to 0}(\frac{\hat T(a \vec s) + \hat T(- a \vec s) - 2 I}{2a^2}) \psi + \hat V \psi$$

Where $\hat U$ is the unitary operator, $\vec s$ is the spatial position $\vec s =  (\hat x,\hat y, \hat z)^{T}$, $\hat T$ is the [translation operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_operator_(quantum_mechanics)), $I$ is the identity and $V$ is the potential and $\psi$ is the wavefunction. Note: with some trivial Taylor expansion one can regain the regular form of the Schrodinger equation.

Now we play the following trick we pretend $  i a^2/ \hbar =  b $. Thus,

$$ \hat U(i \frac{a^2}{\hbar} t) \psi \sim \frac{\hat T(a \vec s) + \hat T(- a \vec s)}{2} \psi - \frac{a^2}{\hbar^2} \hat V \psi$$

Is this a valid manipulation? How does one estimate the error for finite but "small" $a$?

Comment: What are $a$ and $b$?

Comment: I'm not sure I get you but both $a$ and $b$ are infinitesimals as suggested by the limit

Comment: In your initial limit $b$ is real and so is  the argument of $U$. Is the limit still well defined when you allow $b$ to be complex? Meaning, is the limit the same for every path in the complex plane leading to $b\rightarrow 0$?

Comment: I mean I don't see why the limit wouldn't be well defined (in case I've overlooked something feel free to post an answer)

Comment: @MoreAnonymous Now I understand, thank you! I should have read the question more carefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't be sure, but it feels like you are attempting to deconstruct Dirac's [paper](https://www.hep.anl.gov/czachos/soysoy/Dirac33.pdf) analogously to Feynman's nonrelativistic [propagator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagator#Non-relativistic_propagators).
My sense is linking *x* with *t* is mixing up apples and oranges badly. In fact, they enter the picture dramatically differently. In the Schrödinger picture, *before* the irrelevant *x* variable enters,
$$
|\psi (t)\rangle= \hat U(t) |\psi(0)\rangle ,\\
\hat U (t) = \exp \left (-it\frac{\hat H}{\hbar}\right ).
$$
No *x*s around.

If you, nevertheless, chose to work in the x representation, you'd dot by the requisite bra,
$$
\psi (x,t) = \langle x|\psi(t)\rangle= \langle x|\hat U(t) |\psi(0)\rangle\\  = \exp \left (-it\frac{\hat H_x}{\hbar}\right ) \psi(x,0),
$$
where, *only now*, $\hat H_x= -\hbar^2 \nabla^2/2m +V(x)  $, in the x-representation, as customary, having been pulled out of the bracket. This is an exact relation, where *only* the *b* limit has been taken, but before (essentially) the *a* limit formulation, which is superfluous.

You may expand for small *t* as you wish (the *b* limit), and supplant the origin of time to the standard *t*, to obtain the differential form of the Schrödinger equation--but who needs it?

But note the differential operators in the exponent need *further & independent* (and pointless!) effort to connect to translation operators--they are independent variables, and no advantage is gotten from that: the antecedent to the *a* limit for the second space derivative is not a meaningful  exact finite relation, for the same reason it is not salutary to integrate in x-space, instead of Fourier-transforming like Feynman.